# Show that $P\left(X>n \cdot E(X)\right) \leq \frac{1}{n}$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables

> $X$ is a random variable with $P(X>0)= 1$ and $Var(X) = 1$. Show that
>   for all $n$ with $n \geq 1$ it is $P\left(X>n \cdot E(X)\right) \leq
> \frac{1}{n}$

I'm not sure how this is done correctly but at first glance it looks quite similar to Markov's inequality which is (taken from Wikipedia): $$P(X \geq a) \leq \frac{E(X)}{a} \,\,\, \,\,\,\,\,\text{ for } a > 0$$

I cannot bring it to this form because the $E(X)$ would be in the denominator instead :c I have tried to bring it to this form by doing

$$P(X>E(X)) \leq \frac{\frac{1}{n}}{n} \Leftrightarrow P(X>E(X)) \leq \frac{1}{n^2}$$

And now it's reminding me of Chebyshev's inequality which is saying that not more than $\frac{1}{n^2}$ of distribution values can be more than $n$ standard deviations away from $E(X)$ but well it's not really the Chebyshev inequality either so I don't know how I would continue here? :/

Comment: Why can't you take $a=n\mathsf{E}X$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By Markov:

$$P\left[X > nE[X]\right] \le \frac{E[X]}{nE[X]} = \frac{1}{n}$$

Note that you can take $a= nE[X]$